# Function SCOPE_IDENTITY not found

Tags: sybase, identity

When I call `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in Sybase, I get

> [Error] Script lines: 1-6 --------------------------  Function 'SCOPE_IDENTITY' not found. If this is a SQLJ function or SQL
>   function, use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may
>   produce a large amount of output).  Msg: 14216, Level: 16, State: 1 
>   Server: DGTSYBASEDEV101, Line: 3

This is my code:

```
INSERT into IVR_SESSION (PHONE_NUMBER,IVR_TYPE, CALLING_COUNTRY,ADD_DATETIME,UPDATE_DATETIME)
values ("464545454", "asdd", "AUS",getdate(),getdate())
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function is not available in Sybase ASE as it is specific to Microsoft Sql Server. If you want to obtain the last identity value that was generated you can use the `@@IDENTITY` global variable like so:

```
insert into sales_daily (syb_identity, stor_id) 
     values (102, "1349")
select @@identity
```

You can find the documentation for the `@@IDENTITY` global variable at [SyBooks Online](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X39476.htm).

Comment: Ok, I think I misread the documentation. I interpreted this page to mean that Sybase does support scope_identity, but now that I take a closer look at the page, I think this page is outraded/not relevant. http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00042_0250/html/dwbparm/CDFFIHGA.htm   Indeed, that page is referring to datawindow.net, whatever that is.

Comment: Quite possibly as SAP have now bought Sybase so the documentation may not be getting kept up to date on that site. I did notice that near the top it says  *Applies to SNC SQL Native Client for Microsoft SQL Server* though